# How can I change the values of a factor variable as they correspond to original chr values

Tags: r

For example, I'm using a dataset with the variable "hypertension". Originally, the values were from 0 (no hypertension) to 1 (yes hypertension). However, once I converted from chr to factor, the values changed to 1 (no hypertension) and 2 (yes hypertension), while the levels remained 0 and 1. How can I get it to go back to binary, for organization purposes?
[Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jcKb.png)

I don't know where to start. Not great at R. I tried subtracting the levels by one, but instead the levels themselves substracted, not the values, so my levels went from 0 and 1 to -1 and 0.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately now I am not being able to reproduce your problem, but I have faced it before.

Try converting it first to numeric, and then to factor.

```
nums <- c(rep("0", 3), rep("1", 3))

as.factor(as.numeric(nums))
```

Comment: Thank you! This works to fit my levels to my data, which works as a fix. Now, it shows levels as "1" and "2" and the values are 1 and 2. Is there any way, however, to fit the data to the levels, so that the levels are 0 and 1, and the values are 0 and 1?

Comment: `as.numeric(as.character (nums))`